# SQL Server Output Different Results When Using Typed or Copied Values

Tags: sql, ssms

```
select Name_full
from bat_avg
where name_full = 'A.J. Burnett' -- Typed manually, not work
```

```
select Name_full
from bat_avg
where name_full = 'A.J. Burnett' -- Copied from table, work
```

When I try to execute these two code in SSMS, it gave me different results.

These two code visually look the same, but

- for the 1st code, I manually typed **'A.J. Burnett'** into the where clause. And it outputs zero records.
- For the 2nd code, **'A.J. Burnett'** was directly copied from the table value, and it successfully output all matched records.

For the information, the data type for column **name_full** is nvarchar(50)

Is there any reason why it is working like this? and how can I fix the 1st code

Comment: I realized it may because of the datalength of nvarchar values in the table, but not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

to search on nvarchar columns you can do the following

```
select Name_full
  from bat_avg
where name_full = N'A.J. Burnett' -- Typed manually, not work
```

However i think this is not the reason why you are missing the recrod. It could be possible there is a special character between A.J.<> that gets copied when you copy from table directly vs, using "SPACE" while you type

Comment: Hi George, thank you for the answer. I have figured it out it was the space character got encoded wrongly and I have replaced them with the correct ones. No more issues now!